# Integration Testing Rest Controllers assertEquals fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, integration-testing

The response im getting from the serve is blank and I am not sure as to why. I've provided what i've worked through so far. Im following a tutorial, the goal is just to rest the rest controller by comparing my expected string to the actual string. Thanks so much for any help.

Here is my application

```
package com.books.gallo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication()
public class BooksRestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BooksRestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is the controller

```
package com.books.gallo.resource.impl;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.books.gallo.domain.Book;
import com.books.gallo.resource.Resource;
import com.books.gallo.service.BookService;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BookResourceImpl implements Resource<Book> {

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;


    @GetMapping("/testing")
    public String test(){
        return String.format("test has run");
    }

    
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Book>> findAll(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bookService.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Book> findById(Long id){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bookService.findById(id), HttpStatus.OK);
        
    }
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Book> save(Book book){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bookService.save(book), HttpStatus.CREATED);
        
    }
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Book> update(Book book){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bookService.update(book), HttpStatus.OK);
        
    }
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Book> deleteById(Long id){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bookService.deleteById(id), HttpStatus.OK);
        
    }
    

}
```

Here is my test

```
package com.books.gallo.resource.impl;

import com.books.gallo.service.impl.BookServiceImpl;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.RequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(BookResourceImpl.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {BookServiceImpl.class})
class IntegrationBookResourceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    void test1() throws Exception {
        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/books/testing");
        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(request).andReturn();
        assertEquals("test has run", result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }
}
```

```
This is the error


MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /books/testing
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = []
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :test has run
Actual   :

Update after removal of @ContextConfiguration(classes = {BookServiceImpl.class})

[See Error Image below][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pKR8.png
```

Comment: Hello MGallo  :)
can you also please provide the class where the annotation @SpringBootApplication can be found (include the package name)?

Comment: @FluffyDestroyerOfCode just added it to the top of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing the Annotation @ContextConfiguration in the class IntegrationBookResourceImplTest. This Annotation is used to load the spring configuration, which is normally a class annotated with @Configuration. There you also add beans you want spring to manage for you, etc.

For a start this example should work:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(BookResourceImpl.class)
//@ContextConfiguration(classes = {BookServiceImpl.class}) // this messes up your spring config, here you normally declare spring config classes, which are annotated with @Configuration
class IntegrationBookResourceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    void test1() throws Exception {
        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/books/testing");
        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(request).andReturn();
        assertEquals("test has run", result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }
}
```

You have to ensure the spring knows how to create your custom beans. For now you could edit your BooksRestApplication like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BooksRestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BooksRestApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean 
    public BookService bookService () {
        return new BookService();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had added the Context configuration because otherwise when I run my test my application fails to start an im told my application context hasn't loaded. I just added a photo that error. See the png at the end of the original post

Comment: Sry, I have updated my answer. Look at the class BooksRestApplication.